# Cakephp point php file for ajax and include php file to Cakephp

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cakephp

i'm trying to run ajax script to connect to mysql under cake. I'm having trouble with attaching file and run ajax script also.

```
<div>
   <?php foreach ($tasks as $questions) : ?>

        <?php echo $questions['Question']['name'].'<br>'; ?>
        <?php $answers = unserialize($questions['Question']['answers']) ?>
            1.<?php echo 'A.'.$answers[0]; ?><input type="radio" value="<?php $answers[0] ?>" name="a" ><br>
            2.<?php echo 'B.'.$answers[1]; ?><input type="radio" value="<?php $answers[1] ?>" name="a"><br>
            3.<?php echo 'C.'.$answers[2]; ?><input type="radio" value="<?php $answers[0] ?>" name="a"><br>
            4.<?php echo 'D.'.$answers[3]; ?><input type="radio" value="<?php $answers[0] ?>" name="a"><br>
   <?php endforeach;  ?>

</div>
<script>
    $(':radio').click(function() {
        if($(':radio:checked').length === 1) {
            var val = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
               type: "POST", 
                url: "question.php",  
               //data: {"a":val}
            });
       }
   });
</script>
```

In controller i have

App::uses('questions', 'Vendor');

which indicates on questions.php file in app/Vendor/questions.php

is it correct ? i can't find suitable for me option here [Cakebook](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/app.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send request to controller/action:
suppose we have QuestionController add an action named getquesetion then import file from Vender folder in getquesetion action like:

```
`function getquesetion (){
   App::uses('questions', 'Vendor');
}`
```

and  js code is below

```
`$.ajax({
   type: "POST", 
   url: "questions/getquesetion", 
});`
```